# Proving surjectivity exponential function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I need prove that this function is surjective

$f: \mathbb{R} \to (0,1) $

$f(x)= \dfrac{1}{1+e^x}  $

These are my steps:

Let $x \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x)=y$

$f(x)= \dfrac{1}{1+e^x}  $

$y= \dfrac{1}{1+e^x}  $

$1+e^x=\dfrac{1}{y} $

$e^x=\dfrac{1}{y}-1 $

$x=\ln (\dfrac{1}{y}-1) $

I need help for to arrive the next steps such that $f(x)=y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac  1 y >1$ because $0<y<1$. So $\frac 1 y -1 >0$ and $\ln (\frac 1 y -1 )$ is a well -defined real number. This finshes the proof. [You get $f(x)=y$ by retracing your steps].

Comment: how can you get to $f(x)=y$ ? you only use the logarithm argument. It is enough?

Comment: @Jason You get $f(x)=y$ by retracing your steps.

Comment: don't you need substitute $x$ in $ f(x)$ ?

Comment: Start with your last equaion. That defines an $x$ for  a given $y$. Working backwards you get $y=\frac  1{1+e^{x}}$. By definition of the function this says $y=f(x)$ @Jason

Answer (score -1):

Another Idea (maybe helps)
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^x} \to D_f=\mathbb{R}\\$$you know $$e^x>0$$so
$$e^x>0\\1+e^x>1\\or\\1 <1+e^x\leq +\infty\\
0 <\frac{1}{1+e^x}<1$$  then we need to prove   $f(x)$ is decreasing function
$$x_1>x_2 \to e^{x_1}>e^{x_2} \\ 
\frac{1}{1+e^{x_1}}<\frac{1}{1+e^{x_2}}\\
f(x_1)<f(x_2)$$ so $f(x)$ is surjective

Comment: This does not prove that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy:I will complete it.

Comment: Do you know the definition of  a surjective function?